# Accessing a service in Kubernetes via the Kubernetes Python client

Tags: python, rest, kubernetes, curl, kubernetes-service

I have a service running in Kubernetes and currently, there are two ways of making GET requests to the REST API.

The first is

```
kubectl port-forward --namespace test service/test-svc 9090
```

and then running

```
curl http://localhost:9090/sub/path \
-d param1=abcd \
-d param2=efgh \
-G
```

For the second one, we do a kubctl proxy

```
kubectl proxy --port=8080
```

followed by

```
curl -lk 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/namespaces/test/services/test-svc:9090/proxy/sub/path?param1=abcd&param2=efgh'
```

Both work nicely. However, my question is: How do we repeat one of these with the Python Kubernetes client (https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python)?

Many thanks for your support in advance!

**Progress**

I found a solution that brings us closer to the desired result:

```
from kubernetes import client, config


config.load_kube_config("~/.kube/config", context="my-context")

api_instance = client.CoreV1Api()



name = 'test-svc' # str | name of the ServiceProxyOptions
namespace = 'test' # str | object name and auth scope, such as for teams and projects

api_response = api_instance.api_client.call_api(
'/api/v1/namespaces/{namespace}/services/{name}/proxy/ping'.format(namespace=namespace, name=name), 'GET',
    auth_settings = ['BearerToken'], response_type='json', _preload_content=False
)

print(api_response)
```

yet the result is

```
(<urllib3.response.HTTPResponse object at 0x104529340>, 200, HTTPHeaderDict({'Audit-Id': '1ad9861c-f796-4e87-a16d-8328790c50c3', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, private', 'Content-Length': '16', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Date': 'Thu, 27 Jan 2022 15:05:10 GMT', 'Server': 'uvicorn'}))
```

Whereas the desired output was

```
{
  "ping": "pong!"
}
```

Do you know how to extract it form here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be something which uses:

```
from kubernetes.stream import portforward
```

To find which command maps to an API call in Python, you can used

```
kubectl -v 10 ...
```

For example:

```
k -v 10 port-forward --namespace znc service/znc 1666
```

It spits a lot of output, the most important out put is the curl commands:

```
POST https://myk8s:16443/api/v1/namespaces/znc/pods/znc-57647bb8d8-dcq6b/portforward 101 Switching Protocols in 123 milliseconds
```

This allows you to search the code of the python client. For example there is:

```
core_v1.connect_get_namespaced_pod_portforward
```

However, using it is not so straight forward. Luckily, the maintainers include a great example on how to use [portforward method](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/b313b5e74f7cf222ccc39d8c5bf8a07502bd6db3/examples/pod_portforward.py):

```
# Copyright 2020 The Kubernetes Authors.
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

"""
Shows the functionality of portforward streaming using an nginx container.
"""

import select
import socket
import time

import six.moves.urllib.request as urllib_request

from kubernetes import config
from kubernetes.client import Configuration
from kubernetes.client.api import core_v1_api
from kubernetes.client.rest import ApiException
from kubernetes.stream import portforward

##############################################################################
# Kubernetes pod port forwarding works by directly providing a socket which
# the python application uses to send and receive data on. This is in contrast
# to the go client, which opens a local port that the go application then has
# to open to get a socket to transmit data.
#
# This simplifies the python application, there is not a local port to worry
# about if that port number is available. Nor does the python application have
# to then deal with opening this local port. The socket used to transmit data
# is immediately provided to the python application.
#
# Below also is an example of monkey patching the socket.create_connection
# function so that DNS names of the following formats will access kubernetes
# ports:
#
#    <pod-name>.<namespace>.kubernetes
#    <pod-name>.pod.<namespace>.kubernetes
#    <service-name>.svc.<namespace>.kubernetes
#    <service-name>.service.<namespace>.kubernetes
#
# These DNS name can be used to interact with pod ports using python libraries,
# such as urllib.request and http.client. For example:
#
# response = urllib.request.urlopen(
#     'https://metrics-server.service.kube-system.kubernetes/'
# )
#
##############################################################################


def portforward_commands(api_instance):
    name = 'portforward-example'
    resp = None
    try:
        resp = api_instance.read_namespaced_pod(name=name,
                                                namespace='default')
    except ApiException as e:
        if e.status != 404:
            print("Unknown error: %s" % e)
            exit(1)

    if not resp:
        print("Pod %s does not exist. Creating it..." % name)
        pod_manifest = {
            'apiVersion': 'v1',
            'kind': 'Pod',
            'metadata': {
                'name': name
            },
            'spec': {
                'containers': [{
                    'image': 'nginx',
                    'name': 'nginx',
                }]
            }
        }
        api_instance.create_namespaced_pod(body=pod_manifest,
                                           namespace='default')
        while True:
            resp = api_instance.read_namespaced_pod(name=name,
                                                    namespace='default')
            if resp.status.phase != 'Pending':
                break
            time.sleep(1)
        print("Done.")

    pf = portforward(
        api_instance.connect_get_namespaced_pod_portforward,
        name, 'default',
        ports='80',
    )
    http = pf.socket(80)
    http.setblocking(True)
    http.sendall(b'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n')
    http.sendall(b'Host: 127.0.0.1\r\n')
    http.sendall(b'Connection: close\r\n')
    http.sendall(b'Accept: */*\r\n')
    http.sendall(b'\r\n')
    response = b''
    while True:
        select.select([http], [], [])
        data = http.recv(1024)
        if not data:
            break
        response += data
    http.close()
    print(response.decode('utf-8'))
    error = pf.error(80)
    if error is None:
        print("No port forward errors on port 80.")
    else:
        print("Port 80 has the following error: %s" % error)

    # Monkey patch socket.create_connection which is used by http.client and
    # urllib.request. The same can be done with urllib3.util.connection.create_connection
    # if the "requests" package is used.
    socket_create_connection = socket.create_connection

    def kubernetes_create_connection(address, *args, **kwargs):
        dns_name = address[0]
        if isinstance(dns_name, bytes):
            dns_name = dns_name.decode()
        dns_name = dns_name.split(".")
        if dns_name[-1] != 'kubernetes':
            return socket_create_connection(address, *args, **kwargs)
        if len(dns_name) not in (3, 4):
            raise RuntimeError("Unexpected kubernetes DNS name.")
        namespace = dns_name[-2]
        name = dns_name[0]
        port = address[1]
        if len(dns_name) == 4:
            if dns_name[1] in ('svc', 'service'):
                service = api_instance.read_namespaced_service(name, namespace)
                for service_port in service.spec.ports:
                    if service_port.port == port:
                        port = service_port.target_port
                        break
                else:
                    raise RuntimeError(
                        "Unable to find service port: %s" % port)
                label_selector = []
                for key, value in service.spec.selector.items():
                    label_selector.append("%s=%s" % (key, value))
                pods = api_instance.list_namespaced_pod(
                    namespace, label_selector=",".join(label_selector)
                )
                if not pods.items:
                    raise RuntimeError("Unable to find service pods.")
                name = pods.items[0].metadata.name
                if isinstance(port, str):
                    for container in pods.items[0].spec.containers:
                        for container_port in container.ports:
                            if container_port.name == port:
                                port = container_port.container_port
                                break
                        else:
                            continue
                        break
                    else:
                        raise RuntimeError(
                            "Unable to find service port name: %s" % port)
            elif dns_name[1] != 'pod':
                raise RuntimeError(
                    "Unsupported resource type: %s" %
                    dns_name[1])
        pf = portforward(api_instance.connect_get_namespaced_pod_portforward,
                         name, namespace, ports=str(port))
        return pf.socket(port)
    socket.create_connection = kubernetes_create_connection

    # Access the nginx http server using the
    # "<pod-name>.pod.<namespace>.kubernetes" dns name.
    response = urllib_request.urlopen(
        'http://%s.pod.default.kubernetes' % name)
    html = response.read().decode('utf-8')
    response.close()
    print('Status Code: %s' % response.code)
    print(html)


def main():
    config.load_kube_config()
    c = Configuration.get_default_copy()
    c.assert_hostname = False
    Configuration.set_default(c)
    core_v1 = core_v1_api.CoreV1Api()

    portforward_commands(core_v1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```